# How to inherit all class attributes, but one? Python

Tags: python, oop

How to inherit all class 'A' attributes and methods, but 'b()'?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        #  attributes
        pass

    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        #  logic
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def b(self):
        #  nothing
        pass
```

do not use this old method( if there is another way to do it ):

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        super().__init__(self, attributes)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: First code is that I have useless function in B class. Second one is that I have to add attribute manually each time I add one in super class

Comment: @malving, if you don't need function in your child classes, why do you declare it in base?

Comment: I have 2 child classes 'Weapon' and 'Armor' when I type Weapon.from_id(2) it returns me an object with id '2', but it's Armor, I don't want Weapon class to return me Armor

Comment: @malving, you should create base class `Equipment` and declare common methods for both classes there. Both `Weapon` and `Armor` should have inheritance from `Equipment`. It will be architecturally correct.

Comment: This is what I have actually done, but not Equipment, I called it 'Item', but it doesn't matter and it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Put `b` in a separate class and don't inherit it?

Comment: @malving, that's why I've written this in comments. Problem you're trying to solve should not exist if your program designed right, so what you've already done is already a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reimplement `b()` to raise an error:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        #  attributes
        pass

    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        #  logic
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        raise TypeError("method b is not supported in class B")
```

Also, if `b()` is a `classmethod`, you should probably override it as a `classmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Put that method in a separate class and don't inherit it.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        #  attributes
        pass

class A1:
    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        #  logic
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Use multiple inheritance when you want that method.

```
class C(A,A1):
    pass
```

Comment: Normally class methods should be declare in class you're working with.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - what is the downside of this non-Normal solution?

Comment: What do you mean? Selected answer is not a solution at all, I have no idea why author have chosen it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - you commented that my answer is not normal - I was asking why you thought that and what the downside is.

Comment: Ofc I haven't, you misinterpreted my comment. I've meant that architecturally your solution could be applied, but this example is not fully represent what benefits multiple inheritance brings. Class with single class method is not the best example, *classmethod* is mostly used as alternative constructor and commonly it's declared in same class or in base class. So I commented to notice that. But in this answer you at least offer something while selected one contains just copy of code from question with minor edit.

Comment: @OlvinRough , I've selected it because there is no other ways to do it, in wwii's method A1 is useless class it can't do what I need, I wanted to get class object using its "id" attribute, I decided to use classmethod which returns self by its "id"

Comment: @malving, you've selected copy of your code. It's your choice, but I still don't clearly understand it.